# How to add image to right area of jumbotron component (bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Hello I want to insert an image to jumbotron component in bootstrap.

I want to insert it into right area of jumbotron. 
I have this code:

```
 <section class="jumbotron text-center"> 
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">My site</h1>
    <p class="lead text-muted">Welcome to our page</p><br>
    <h2 class="jumbotron-heading"><b>Random form</b></h1><br>
...
```

And this is what I get:
[site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DReTN.png)

I need to use css for it or?

Maybe my question is stupid and it cannot be donebut I just now started learning boostrap so please understand me.

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap grid to achieve this (I assume you're using 3.3.7 version).
Adjust the grid responsive breakpoints as needed:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/01/18/47/trimaran-2806616_1280.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Additionally:** if you need to use the image outside of `.container` then you need to wrap container inside the `col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8` div. Again, you probably need to adjust the columns and responsive breakpoints.